# Property testing for membership in span of vectors

Tags: interactive-proofs, property-testing

#### Notation

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field, and  $m, n$ be natural numbers.
An algorithm $A$ is said to have oracle access to a vector $v \in \mathbb{F}^n$ if it can query $v$ with input an index $i \in \{0, \dotsc, n-1\}$, and receive as output the $i$-th entry of $v$, denoted $v[i]$.

Two vectors $v_1, v_2 \in \mathbb{F}^n$ are said to have relative-Hamming distance of $\delta$ if they differ in a $\delta$-fraction of locations. We denote this by $\Delta(v_1, v_2) = \delta$, and say that $v_1$ is $\delta$-far from $v_2$ (and vice versa)

#### Problem statement

Let $\varepsilon\in \mathbb{R}$ be such $0 \leq \varepsilon\leq 1$. Then, design a probabilistic algorithm $A$ that, given oracle access to $m+1$ vectors $t, v_1, \dotsc, v_m \in \mathbb{F}^n$, and given as explicit input $m$ field elements $a_1, \dotsc, a_m \in \mathbb{F}$, decides whether $t$ is $\varepsilon$-far from $s := \sum_{j=1}^m a_j v_j$ with error probability at most $1/3$, that is:
$$
\Pr[A^{t, v_1, \dotsc, v_j}(a_1, \dotsc, a_m) = 1\  \text{and} \ \Delta(t, s) > \varepsilon] < \frac{1}{3}
$$

(Here $1/3$ is just a placeholder; any constant probability bounded away from $1$ suffices.)

#### Preliminary result

The following "trivial" algorithm achieves a constant error probability with $O(\frac{m}{|\log(1-\varepsilon)|}) \approx O(m/\varepsilon)$ queries.

$A^{t, v_1, \dotsc, v_j}(a_1, \dotsc, a_m)$: Repeat the following steps $1/\varepsilon$ times, and output $1$ if all checks pass:

1. Sample an index $i$ uniformly at random from $\{0, \dotsc, n - 1\}$.
2. Query $t, v_1, \dotsc, v_j$ at $i$ to obtain $t[i], v_1[i], \dotsc, v_j[i]$.
3. Check that $t[i] = \sum_{j=1}^m a_j v_j[i]$. If the check fails, halt and output $0$. Otherwise, continue.

It is straightforward to see that if $t$ is at least $\varepsilon$-far from $s$, then at each step, the check will pass with probability at most $1 - \varepsilon$. Thus the algorithm will output $1$ with probability $(1 - \varepsilon)^{1/\varepsilon} < e^{-1} \approx 1/3$. Furthermore, the algorithm clearly makes a total of $(m+1) \cdot \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ queries.

Can one design an algorithm with better query complexity? I would also be interested in seeing an interactive (oracle) proof of proximity for this problem.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something - why is an $\Omega(1/\delta)$ lower bound not immediate (which would prove your upper bound is tight)?

Comment: @ClementC., could you provide some pointers on how to go about deriving the lower bound? Also you are right that it should $m$ times what I had stated previously. I've edited the question to correct this.

Comment: Your algorithm seems to imply it is a promise problem: either $t=s$ or $\Delta(t,s)>\epsilon$. Is this the case? If you want to distinguish $\Delta(t,s)>\epsilon$ from $\Delta(t,s)\leq \epsilon$, I'm pretty sure the query complexity scales with $n$.